# Thunderbird doesn't seem to recognize changes in hosts file

Tags: dns, thunderbird, hosts-file

I want to use Thunderbird (or another software if that's more possible) to access some email that's on a shared hosting server that we pointed our domain away from.

I've managed to get the IP of our old server and modifying my hosts file allows me to see the old site in my browser, problem is that when I try to access an email account from Thunderbird, it seems to be ignoring the hosts file.

Is there some way around this? I saw some complaints about Firefox ignoring the hosts file but I can access the old server fine with Firefox Dev version.

Comment: Are you sure the old mail server is still listening on pop or imap ports? It is possible that was turned off.

Comment: @MrStatic I don't believe the ports were turned off, as I didn't change any settings on the old server, I just changed the name servers for the domain which is managed as a separate service. Thunderbird seems to be able to connect but I get a message that the password is wrong, this makes me believe it's connecting to the new server and not the old one since the passwords are different and I'm entering the old password, if I enter the new password sure enough it shows email from the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem when I realized that the pop subdomain on the old server had its own IP address, I also realized that I had to enter that as its own entry in my hosts file, seems that the hosts file doesn't automatically redirect subdomains, it requires you to enter each subdomain individually.

Final host file looked like this:
123.12.123.1 domain.com
123.12.123.5 pop.domain.com

It may also be possible to just enter the pop subdomain IP address in your mail client but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. Bug in Thunderbird?